# How to identify which UITextField was changed with textFieldDidChange

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, swift4, target-action

I am using several `UITextField`s and want to do anytime anything changes in any one of them.

It looks basically like:

```
@IBOutlet weak var f1: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var f2: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var f3: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    f1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    f2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
    f3.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
}

@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    // Data in one of the fields changed.
    if self.view.tag == 1 {
        print("field 1")
    } else {
        if self.view.tag == 2 {
            print("field 2")
        }
        //...
    }
}
```

As you can see, I've tried setting tags, but not sure how to access them here.

I’m using XCode 9.01 and Swift 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need tags since you have outlets. Just compare the `textField` parameter to each of your outlets:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == f1 {
        print("field 1")
    } else if textField == f2 {
        print("field 2")
    } else if textField == f3 {
        print("field 3")
    }
}
```

Comment: Using a `switch` wouldn’t improve readability a little? Anyway, might be just a matter of taste really... ;)

Comment: @PauloMattos Using a `switch` is another option. Feel free to post an answer showing that solution. I'm a long time Objective-C programmer and I'm still not used to being able to use `switch` for things like this.

Answer (score 3):

A quick, modest improvement over *rmaddy*’s answer:

```
@objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
    switch textField {
    case f1: print("field 1")
    case f2: print("field 2")
    case f3: print("field 3")
    default: fatalError(“Unknown field: \(textField)”)
    }
}
```

Besides using a `switch` — which might slightly improve code readability one may argue — this version also triggers a *runtime error* if an unexpected text field is passed. Luckily, this might just catch a programming error later on ;)

Comment: Personally, I'd change your opening statement to "A quick, alternate solution to rmaddy's answer". Calling it a "modest improvement" is subjective and a matter of taste. :) But it still gets a +1 from me.

Comment: Perfect!  Yes, a switch was coming down the road, this was only to figure out how it worked.  Thank you everyone!

Comment: Hey @Greg, if you went with the `switch` version you should really pick my answer as the accepted one bro ;) Thanks and good luck!

Comment: In all fairness, rmaddy's was first and I had already planned to use switch for what was to come.